# VNR orthogonally finite rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Is it true that a von Neumann regular (VNR) ring having no infinite set of orthogonal idempotents is semisimple?

I know for the proof of the  claim it is sufficient to show that each rght ideal of the ring is a direct summand thereof.
Hence if one proves that each right ideal is finitely generated the answer to the question is "yes".
Thanks for cooperation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true, because it is the same as having the ACC/DCC on summands, which in a VNR ring means finite uniform dimension, hence semisimple.

You can go along the lines you were thinking by considering a right ideal that isn't finitely generated, and show how the ascending chain of summands produced inside can be used to manufacture orthogonal idempotents.